# Unnecessary Dotnet Core MVC "Home" and "Index" URL components?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The default routing and URL generation for Dotnet Core 2.0 MVC produces very weird URLs. I don't remember them being like this in ASP.Net MVC.

i.e. when creating creating a new site using the Dotnet Core MVC template, we see the following URLs generated:

`/Home/About` « I could have sworn this used to just be `/About`

`/Manage/Index` « This definitely used to be `/Manage`

In the first example this is the same in the current ASP.NET MVC (.NET Template) template. I don't remember seeing the "Home" in the URL. That seems weird. Why not just /About?

In the second example there's a difference between the ASP.NET MVC (.NET Template) and the Dotnet Core one. The "Index" on the end is obviously superfluous.

Anyone know what's up here? Is there a simple way to change the default route definition to clean this up?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the way it has always been, but have you looked at attribute routing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks @TonyRanieri. Route attributes have neatened up the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at attribute routing which you could use to declare your routes in this fashion:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("")]
   [Route("Home")]
   [Route("Home/Index")]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
   [Route("Home/About")]
   public IActionResult About()
   {
      return View();
   }
   [Route("Home/Contact")]
   public IActionResult Contact()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing